# How to add pagination using angular material to HTML table

Tags: angular, angularjs, angular-material, angular-pagination

I am trying to paginate my page and show 3 row per page and navigate through pages using angular material pagination.
In **usersComponent.ts** I retrieved Data from an API:

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { MatTableDataSource } from '@angular/material/table';
import { MatPaginator } from '@angular/material/paginator';
 
@Component({
  selector: 'app-users',
  templateUrl: './users.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./users.component.css']
})

export class UsersComponent implements OnInit{
  users: any = [];
  dataSource:MatTableDataSource<UsersComponent>;
  @ViewChild('paginator') paginator:MatPaginator;
  displayColumn: string[]=["ID", "Avatar", "First Name", "Last Name"];
  constructor(private http: HttpClient){}
  ngOnInit(){
    let resp = this.http.get("https://reqres.in/api/users");
    resp.subscribe((data) => this.users = data);
   
  }
  ngAfterInit(){
    this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(this.users);
    this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
  }

}
```

I showed the data in this html table in **users.component.html**:

```
    <ng-container matColumnDef="ID">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> ID </th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.id}} </td>
    </ng-container>

    <ng-container matColumnDef="Avatar">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Avatar </th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> <img src= "{{element.avatar}}"> </td>
    </ng-container>

    <ng-container matColumnDef="First Name">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> First Name </th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">  {{element.first_name}} </td>
    </ng-container>

    <ng-container matColumnDef="Last Name">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Last Name </th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{element.last_name}} </td>
    </ng-container>
    <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayColumn"></tr>
    <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayColumn;"></tr>

  
  </table>
  <mat-paginator class="mat-elevation-z8" #paginator [length]="2"  [pageSizeOptions]="[3,6]">
</mat-paginator>
```

The pagination doesn't work and all pagination's buttons not able to clicked to navigate through pages

Answer (score 1):

You have no data in ngAfterViewInit, else in subscribe function

```
ngOnInit(){
    let resp = this.http.get("https://reqres.in/api/users");
    resp.subscribe((data:any) => {
      //you neend't use an auxiliar variable "users"
      this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(data);
      this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;

      //but also can use
      this.users = data
    };
   
  }
  ngAfterInit(){
    //nothing to do here
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem is that ngAfterInit is not called anywhere.
I think you wanted to use ngAfterViewInit.
Just use `implements OnInit, AfterViewInit` next time to make sure you implemented the right interface.

Also learn how to debug your code so you can actually see if functions are called and variables are initialized correctly, I always use the tools provided by the browser and it has always been enough.

Comment: I've added that it is also not working

Comment: Is this.matSort initialized? Have you checked in debug?