# Angular material pagination not working properlry

Tags: angular, angularjs, material-ui, angular-material

I am trying to show data in HTML table through an API and I want to add pagination to it and show 3 or 6 row per page but it is not working. All data showed without pagination while I looking to show 3, 4 or 6 when users click on pagination buttons.

[image]

#### **users.component.ts:**

```
import { AfterViewInit, Component, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Users } from '../users';
import { ApicallService } from '../apicall.service';
import { MatPaginator } from '@angular/material/paginator';
import { MatTableDataSource } from '@angular/material/table';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-users-data',
  templateUrl: './users-data.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./users-data.component.css']
})
export class UsersDataComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit{
  @ViewChild('paginator') paginator: MatPaginator;
  users : Users[] =[];
  dataSource: MatTableDataSource<Users>;
  constructor(public http: HttpClient, private apiService: ApicallService){}
  displayedColumns: string[] = ['ID', 'Avatar', 'First Name', 'Last Name'];
  
  ngOnInit(){
    this.getUserList();
  }
  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(this.users);
    this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
  }

  getUserList() {
    this.apiService
    .getUsers()
    .subscribe((data:any) => {
      
      this.users = [data.data];
      console.log("users data");
      console.log(this.users);
    });
  }
}
```

here the html table in user.component.html:

```
<div class="mat-elevation-z8">
        <table mat-table [dataSource]="users">
      
        
          <ng-container matColumnDef="ID">
            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> ID </th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.id}} </td>
          </ng-container>
      

          <ng-container matColumnDef="Avatar">
            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> avatar </th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> <img src="{{element.avatar}} "> </td>
          </ng-container>
      

          <ng-container matColumnDef="First Name">
            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> First Name </th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.first_name}} </td>
          </ng-container>
      

          <ng-container matColumnDef="Last Name">
            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Last Name </th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.last_name}} </td>
          </ng-container>
      
          <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
          <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>
        </table>
        <mat-paginator #paginator [pageSizeOptions]="[2, 4, 6]" 
        showFirstLastButtons></mat-paginator>
</div>
```

Comment: Keylen it's the same question that this another [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77031604/how-to-add-pagination-using-angular-material-to-html-table/77032586#77032586) from another user

Answer (score 0, accepted):

because you should assign dataSource to the table, and nost just users.

fix: put `ngAfterViewInit` body inside of subscribe and bind the ds instead of just array

```
getUserList() {
    this.apiService
    .getUsers()
    .subscribe((data:any) => {
      this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(data.data);
      this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
    });
  }
.....
<table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource">
```